# Logits and labels must have the same shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, word-embedding

I am creating a multi-label text classification model by trying to adapt these two tutorials: [Word embeddings](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings) and [Multi-Label Classification with Deep Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-label-classification-with-deep-learning/).

I am using my own dataset where the input is a string of tokens separated by a space. The strings have variable length. The output is a list containing 13 binary values (0 or 1).

Here is my code:

```py
vocabulary_size = 314
max_sequence_length = 726663

# Corpus and labels are lists loaded via custom scripts
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((corpus_x, labels_x))
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((corpus_y, labels_y))

text_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)

vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(standardize="lower", max_tokens=vocabulary_size,
                                    output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=max_sequence_length)

vectorize_layer.adapt(text_ds)

embedding_dimension = 16
number_of_outputs = len(labels_x[0])

model = Sequential([vectorize_layer,
                    Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_dimension, name="embedding"),
                    #GlobalAveragePooling1D(), Dense(embedding_dimension, activation="relu"),
                    Dense(embedding_dimension, activation="relu"),
                    Dense(number_of_outputs, activation="sigmoid")])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=15)
```

The error I get is

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "embedding.py", line 137, in <module>
    model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=15)
    ...
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 13) vs (13, 1)).
```

The commented line with the Pooling layer is there because the Tensorflow tutorial put it there but that gives me another error:

```py
Input 0 of layer "global_average_pooling1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 16)
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: What is the shape of `train_ds`?

Comment: @Djinn print(train_ds.element_spec) outputs : (TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(13,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))

Comment: @Djinn I don't know how to get the shape from the corpus_x part other than its a list of 4198 variable length strings, with the longest strings having 726663 words.

Comment: Your model is expecting an array of thirteen float elements in the label but it's being passed labels with thirteen arrays of single element arrays.

Comment: @Djinn I understand that, but how does a tensor of shape (13,) get translated into (13,1). And how can I reshape this?

Comment: The elements are on the wrong axis most likely. (5,) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. (5, 1) = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]].

Comment: maybe you should reshape `data = data.reshape(13, 1)` or `reshape(-1, 1)`